# How to run a function when a Notification is pressed?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've got a simple function that creates a Notification. When the notification is pressed, the user is redirected to a given url:

```
// makes an immediate notification
public void makeNotification(int icon, String title, String description,
        String url, CharSequence tickerText) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

        CharSequence contentTitle = title;
        CharSequence contentText = description;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText,
                contentIntent);

        // make each notification unique
        mNM.notify(currentNotificationId, notification);
        currentNotificationId++;
}
```

I'd like to run a function (to track how many notification clicks) whenever the Notification is pressed. How would I accomplish this?

I could create some intermediate activity (that runs the function and then forwards user to the url) which gets passed into the PendingIntent instead of the Intent.ACTION_VIEW, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing PendingIntent.getActivity(), do PendingIntent.getBroadcast() and write your broadcast receiver along with your app. Now when user touches the notification, your broadcast receiver will get activated (pass url as intent data).

Inside onRecieve() of broadcast receiver, do your logic and start the browser activity as you do now.